# How does GLM achieve quaternion crossing and normalization?

Tags: c++, math, rust, glm-math, raytracing

I'm trying to follow [TheCherno](https://www.youtube.com/@TheCherno)'s ray tracing series in Rust (Currently on [Episode 6](https://github.com/TheCherno/RayTracing/commit/9d87678b428f2957c860483d84850449245769c9)), but I've run into a mathematical roadblock. I'm uncertain what to do about this bit of code:

```
if (delta.x != 0.0f || delta.y != 0.0f)
    {
        float pitchDelta = delta.y * GetRotationSpeed();
        float yawDelta = delta.x * GetRotationSpeed();

        glm::quat q = glm::normalize(glm::cross(glm::angleAxis(-pitchDelta, rightDirection),
            glm::angleAxis(-yawDelta, glm::vec3(0.f, 1.0f, 0.0f))));
        m_ForwardDirection = glm::rotate(q, m_ForwardDirection);

        moved = true;
    }
```

How does `GLM` allow for crossing and normalizing quaternions? I'm new to the concept, but it doesn't seem mathematically sound. I'm trying to rewrite this code in Rust with the `cgmath` crate, but there is no counterpart to these two `GLM` functions. I've tried finding the source code and implementing the functions myself, but I can't find any mention apart from in the [ancient documentation](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.0/api/a00135.html#acca9518d4cb79922ccbcd2d01e886421).

Comment: What exactly is your question? I'm no mathematician, so I might be way off base here, but quaternions are just 4-D vectors, no? Why wouldn't you be able to normalize them or calculate their cross product?

Comment: @isaactfa Possibly because there is no such thing as a cross product on a 4d vector? (You'd need to use geometric products with geometric algebra for that). 
There is no such thing as a cross product between two quaternions (the cross and dot product were originally just a simplification of the 4D quaternion product). I've checked the source code for GLM::quat::cross, and it's actually just performing a quaternion product. Let's just say that's mathematically a bit rubbish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So anyway, this code is terrible, so don't feel too bad for not understanding it :)

Ok, so what we have here is pretty poor usage of quats tbh. The code is generating two quaternions, one for the rotation around the x axis (I assume), and one around the y axis.

```cpp
auto qr_xaxis = glm::angleAxis(-pitchDelta, rightDirection);
auto qr_yaxis = glm::angleAxis(-yawDelta, glm::vec3(0.f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

`cross` in GLM is actually just multiply - naming it `cross` is very wrong indeed! Effectively all this is doing is combining the X and Y axis rotations into a single rotation:

```cpp
glm::quat q = qr_xaxis * qr_yaxis;
```

For reasons unknown, the author has decided that normalising the result here is a *good idea*. There shouldn't be any need to normalise that quat here, because by definition `qr_xaxis` and `qr_yaxis` are already normalised, and the quat product of two unit quaternions is always a unit quaternion.

Finally, its rotating m_ForwardDirection by the combined quat.

```cpp
        m_ForwardDirection = glm::rotate(q, m_ForwardDirection);
```

Honestly, I'm not entirely sure what this code is trying to do, but I will say that the original authors understanding of how quaternions work, is clearly *not great*. I'd treat his tutorial series with a large dose of salt as a result...